# Android style call log

Tags: android, listview, call

I have to create an activity similar to the Android's call log. I haven't found much info about it. what I found is this example, that has a main activity where there are 3 buttons:

1. Outgoing call list
2. Ingoing call list
3. Missed call list

And each button sends to another activity which is a listview with the details of each call.

But what I need, is first to unify all this app into one only layout, which shows all missed, outgoing and ingoing calls at a time, listed by date. I now that this should be simple, but I'm not getting able to do it, this is because I ask you for help. The next thing that I should do after this, is to modify the listview layout to show the call log as Android shows it, with the phone icons and the option to call that person if you touch the name.

But first of all, I need the app running the way I need it.

This is the code for the main layout where there are the 3 buttons:

```
public class CallLogsDemoActivity extends Activity {

    public static ArrayList<CallLogModel> outgoingList;
    public static ArrayList<CallLogModel> incomingList;
    public static ArrayList<CallLogModel> missedcallList;

    public static final int OUTGOING_CALLS = 1;
    public static final int INCOMING_CALLS = 2;
    public static final int MISSED_CALLS = 3;

    public static final String CALL_TYPE = "TYPE";

    private Button inBtn, outBtn, missedBtn;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        outBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        inBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        missedBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        inBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showIncomingList();
            }
        });
        outBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showOutGoingList();
            }
        });
        missedBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showMissedList();
            }
        });
        outgoingList = new ArrayList<CallLogModel>();
        incomingList = new ArrayList<CallLogModel>();
        missedcallList = new ArrayList<CallLogModel>();

        new ReadLogs().execute();
    }

    private void showIncomingList() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallLogs.class);
        intent.putExtra(CALL_TYPE, INCOMING_CALLS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void showMissedList() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallLogs.class);
        intent.putExtra(CALL_TYPE, MISSED_CALLS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void showOutGoingList() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallLogs.class);
        intent.putExtra(CALL_TYPE, OUTGOING_CALLS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private String getDuration(long milliseconds) {
        int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60;
        int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
        int hours = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        if (hours < 1)
            return minutes + ":" + seconds;
        return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }

    private String getDateTime(long milliseconds) {
        Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
        //return DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

        return date.toLocaleString();
    }

    private void readCallLogs() {

        missedcallList.clear();
        incomingList.clear();
        outgoingList.clear();

        Cursor callLogCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
        if (callLogCursor != null) {
            while (callLogCursor.moveToNext()) {
                String id = callLogCursor.getString(callLogCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID));
                String name = callLogCursor.getString(callLogCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
                String cacheNumber = callLogCursor.getString(callLogCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL));
                String number = callLogCursor.getString(callLogCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
                long dateTimeMillis = callLogCursor.getLong(callLogCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));
                long durationMillis = callLogCursor.getLong(callLogCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
                int callType = callLogCursor.getInt(callLogCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));

                String duration = getDuration(durationMillis * 1000);

                String dateString = getDateTime(dateTimeMillis);

                if (cacheNumber == null)
                    cacheNumber = number;
                if (name == null)
                    name = "No Name";

                CallLogModel callLogModel = new CallLogModel(name, cacheNumber,
                        duration, dateString);
                if (callType == CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE) {
                    outgoingList.add(callLogModel);

                } else if (callType == CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE) {
                    incomingList.add(callLogModel);

                } else if (callType == CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE) {
                    missedcallList.add(callLogModel);

                }

            }
            callLogCursor.close();
        }
    }

    private class ReadLogs extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        /* Object */
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        /*
         * Function name: onPreExecute Parameters: Void params Return: void
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CallLogsDemoActivity.this,
                    "Reading Call Logs...", "Please wait...", true);
        }

        /*
         * Function name: doInBackground Parameters: Void params Return: void
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            readCallLogs();
            return null;
        }

        /*
         * Function name: onPostExecute Parameters: Void result Return: void
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the other activity which shows the list:

```
public class CallLogs extends Activity {
    private ListView mainListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<CallLogModel> listAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mainListView.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int callType = extras.getInt(CallLogsDemoActivity.CALL_TYPE);
        if (callType == CallLogsDemoActivity.OUTGOING_CALLS)
            listAdapter = new CallLogsArrayAdapter(this,
                    CallLogsDemoActivity.outgoingList);
        else if (callType == CallLogsDemoActivity.INCOMING_CALLS)
            listAdapter = new CallLogsArrayAdapter(this,
                    CallLogsDemoActivity.incomingList);
        else if (callType == CallLogsDemoActivity.MISSED_CALLS)
            listAdapter = new CallLogsArrayAdapter(this,
                    CallLogsDemoActivity.missedcallList);
        mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }

    public void initElements() {
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

As said, I tried to unify this code to show in one only layout and show all call types at a time as Android does it, but didn't achieve it.

Comment: What problem are you facing. Isn't list shown or you facing any crash?

Comment: Ok, Now I got it, You want all the call types to be shown in one list. Not filtered on any type. Right?

Comment: @Changdeo Jadhav when trying to unify all, I get not to crash the app, but the list doesn't show nothing. What I want is to all call types to be shown in one list, not filtered on the list... but I want to mantain each calls type then to add an icon to each call depending if it is a missedcall, outoging call or ingoing call

Answer (score 1):

Change this code

```
int callType = extras.getInt(CallLogsDemoActivity.CALL_TYPE);
if (callType == CallLogsDemoActivity.OUTGOING_CALLS)
    listAdapter = new CallLogsArrayAdapter(this,
            CallLogsDemoActivity.outgoingList);
else if (callType == CallLogsDemoActivity.INCOMING_CALLS)
    listAdapter = new CallLogsArrayAdapter(this,
            CallLogsDemoActivity.incomingList);
else if (callType == CallLogsDemoActivity.MISSED_CALLS)
    listAdapter = new CallLogsArrayAdapter(this,
            CallLogsDemoActivity.missedcallList);
mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

To this

```
        int callType = extras.getInt(CallLogsDemoActivity.CALL_TYPE);
    ArrayList<CallLogModel> collectiveList = new ArrayList<CallLogModel>();
    collectiveList.addAll(CallLogsDemoActivity.outgoingList);
    collectiveList.addAll(CallLogsDemoActivity.incomingList);
    collectiveList.addAll(CallLogsDemoActivity.missedcallList);
    listAdapter = new CallLogsArrayAdapter(this,collectiveList);
    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: Or you have only one list in returned from your asynctask and use it instead of adding all in one later.

Comment: Thanks @Changdeo Jadhav, this way I get the 3 call types in the same arraylist. But I still need to unify both activities. I mean, when I start the app, directly go to the call log, without having these 3 buttons

Comment: I'll set this answer as accepted if you can help me with this.